# Perl undefined yp_get_default_domain detected by DynaLoader.pm when using ARSperl, yet library exists

Tags: perl, perl-module, undefined-symbol

I have a Ubuntu server that recently pushed a Perl update to 5.14.2 when I installed cpanminus.  This broke compatibility with the BMC Remedy API module.  It looks like I can't roll back to the old version of Perl, so I've tried recompiling ARSperl for Perl 5.14.2.

The problem is, when I run an old Perl script that used the old module, I get the following:

```
Can't load '/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/auto/ARS/ARS.so' for module ARS:
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/auto/ARS/ARS.so: undefined symbol:
yp_get_default_domain at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/i686-linux/DynaLoader.pm line 190.
```

So, a bit of Googling tells me that yp_get_default_domain lives in libnsl.  I've gone so far as to try recompiling both the ARSperl module and Perl itself with "-lnsl" explicitly called out in the Makefile.  Unfortunately, this has gotten me nowhere.  The library is indeed installed on the system under /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/.

In ARSperl Makefile:

`LDFLAGS =  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lnsl`

My question is therefore two-fold for the Perl gurus out there.

-How can I determine which of Perl, DynaLoader, or the ARS.so itself can't find "yp_get_default_domain"?

-What is the best next step to troubleshoot the above DynaLoader message for a missing library that is actually present on the system and linked in the module?

Thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Add the directory where library is installed to the $ARS_LDPATH in Makefile.PL

Something like

```
$ARSAPI      = "C:\\ARS_Library\\api764win";

if( $WINDOWS ){
  $ARS_LDPATH = qq{-L"$ARSAPI/lib"};
  $INCLUDES   = qq{-I"$ARSAPI/include"};
}else{
  $ARS_LDPATH = "-L$ARSAPI/lib";
  $INCLUDES   = "-I$ARSAPI/include";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I wouldn't have thought to look there,  it does seem like a very logical place.

Since it doesn't look like the file handles multiple paths in the $INCLUDES, I went ahead and copied all the AR header files into /usr/include, copied all the AR lib files from /usr/ars/api/lib into /lib/i386-linux-gnu and then set both:

$ARS_LDPATH = "-L/lib/i386-linux-gnu"
$INCLUDES = "-I/usr/include"

Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error back.

It's definitely present though:  
nm -D /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl.so --> 00004170 T yp_get_default_domain

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We updated to ARSperl 1.93, started using AR API version 6.3 rather than 5.1.2 and added "-lsnl" to the ARSperl Makefile.PL $ARS_LIBS in the section for 6.3.

That resulted in Perl segfaulting every time the ARS.so module was run.  After lots of testing and trying to diagnose why segfaults were occurring, we recompiled a separate instance of Perl-5.14.2 from source under /opt/ and removed the 64int option.  Updating the shebang lines on all our Perl scripts that need the ARS module to redirect to the Perl version under /opt seems to have gotten things working again.

Thank you Chankey Pathak for pointing me toward the Makefile.PL, I wouldn't have immediately started looking at changing things there without this advice.